# COMException - Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

After an enjoyable weekend I walked into work this morning, opened up Chrome, navigated to my client's production Tridion as normal - WHAM - COM Exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {9926D1CF-F158-418F-A9A2-B653B497D982} failed due to the following
>   error: 80004005 Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005
>   (E_FAIL)).

This appears to be the CM_TOM.dll - problem is I've restarted COM servers, IIS etc. but nothing seems to work.

I'm about to restart the machine but wondered if anyone here had come across this before?

Comment: Nice - so Windows was unloading your Tridion user (MTSUser) profile?

Comment: Please add your edit as an answer and accept it. Because it sounds **very** useful for others with the same error message.

Comment: I had the same thing, when I lost the password to my MTSUser and I decided to (temporarily of course) run the Tridion com+ under my own account.. A better solution is not to use the MTSUser to log in with at all.

Comment: Removed my edit and created as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, for future reference - resolved this via the following steps:

- Open the Global Policy Editor snap-in.
- Go to Computer Configuration >
  Administrative Templates > System > UserProfiles.
- Double-click 'Do
  not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff'
- SelectcEnabled and click OK.
- Reboot the server